# Vuetify options not taken into account in vue-cli library build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, vue-cli

My app is correctly wrapped with `<v-app>` and my vuetify options work fine in development mode or if I build normally using `vue-cli-service build` for example.

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'fa',
  theme: {
    primary: '#213e79',
    secondary: '#c0d8ed', 
    accent: '#4ea3ed',
    error: '#b71c1c',
    info: '#2196f3',
    success: '#66bb6a', 
    warning: '#f57f17'
  }
});
```

However, if I build in **library mode** (ex: `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name xxx`), the above options are **NOT** taken into account. I'm forced to modify `vuetify/dist/vuetify.js` for lack of a better solution..

Any idea what could be the issue ? If any of you has a workaround laying around, that would be great :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the Vue CLI's build target is `lib`, your original entry point (e.g. `main.js`) is not used. This behavior is described in the [Vue CLI docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#using-vuex-in-builds). This entry point file is where the Vuetify plugin is typically imported. To work around this, simply move the import of Vuetify into the main `.vue` component in your project. This is usually called `App.vue`, but may have another name if you didn't use the CLI to scaffold your project.

In the main `.vue` file, import Vuetify and your Vuetify options. Then, in the component declaration, simply include a `vuetify` property populated with your imported Vuetify instance. Below is the `App.vue` component from Vuetify's basic "Hello World" sample app, modified for compatibility with exporting as a `lib`:

```
<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';

import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'     //IMPORT THE VUETIFY CONFIG FILE

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),

  vuetify, //ADD IT TO THE COMPONENT DECLARATION
};
</script>
```

**Update:**

In order to load Vuetify in a component using Vuetify 2.x, the Vuetify plugin file should follow this pattern:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import '@/assets/stylus/main.styl';

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify ({
  iconfont: 'fa',
  theme: {
    primary: '#213e79',
    secondary: '#c0d8ed',
    accent: '#4ea3ed',
    error: '#b71c1c',
    info: '#2196f3',
    success: '#66bb6a',
    warning: '#f57f17'
  }
})
```

**FOR VUETIFY 1.5.x**

There are a few differences when using Vuetify 1.5.x instead of Vuetify 2.x.

First, it is not necessary to include the vuetify object in the component declaration. You should still import the `./plugins/vuetify` file.

Second, the theme and icons must be configured separately in the `beforeCreate` life-cycle hook. Here is an example:

```
beforeCreate() {

    //Override the default icons with the Font-Awesome preset
    this.$vuetify.icons = {
      'complete': 'fas fa-check',
      'cancel': 'fas fa-times-circle',
      'close': 'fas fa-times',
      'delete': 'fas fa-times-circle', // delete (e.g. v-chip close)
      'clear': 'fas fa-times-circle', // delete (e.g. v-chip close)
      'success': 'fas fa-check-circle',
      'info': 'fas fa-info-circle',
      'warning': 'fas fa-exclamation',
      'error': 'fas fa-exclamation-triangle',
      'prev': 'fas fa-chevron-left',
      'next': 'fas fa-chevron-right',
      'checkboxOn': 'fas fa-check-square',
      'checkboxOff': 'far fa-square', // note 'far'
      'checkboxIndeterminate': 'fas fa-minus-square',
      'delimiter': 'fas fa-circle', // for carousel
      'sort': 'fas fa-sort-up',
      'expand': 'fas fa-chevron-down',
      'menu': 'fas fa-bars',
      'subgroup': 'fas fa-caret-down',
      'dropdown': 'fas fa-caret-down',
      'radioOn': 'far fa-dot-circle',
      'radioOff': 'far fa-circle',
      'edit': 'fas fa-edit',
      'ratingEmpty': 'far fa-star',
      'ratingFull': 'fas fa-star',
      'ratingHalf': 'fas fa-star-half'
    }

    //Override the theme colors.
    this.$vuetify.theme = {
        primary: '#213e79',
        secondary: '#c0d8ed', 
        accent: '#4ea3ed',
        error: '#b71c1c',
        info: '#2196f3',
        success: '#66bb6a', 
        warning: '#f57f17'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason and thank you for your answer, I tried this just right now. Check out this [pen](https://codepen.io/Jakensen/pen/JjoZrvo) where you'll find my App.vue file (in the HTML section) and my vuetify configuration file (in the JS section). I opened the generated demo.html file in my dist folter and my options are still not taken into account and I have no idea why.. I briefly saw your beforeCreate hook idea could you repost it so that I can give it a try ? Thanks again for all your help

Comment: Thank you Jason but I tried that already as well, I'm getting the following webpack error : Uncaught TypeError: vuetify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a is not a constructor (see my updated [pen](https://codepen.io/Jakensen/pen/JjoZrvo))

Comment: What version of Vuetify are you using?

Comment: 1.5.21 for the comment, we will upgrade to v2 shortly. Update : the beforeCreate hook works, could be a temporary solution until we switch to v2.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the `beforeCreate` hook for Vuetify 1.5.x